# Trace the click handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have a click handler bound to a div with an ID, and 4000 lines of javascript/jquery in 10 files... how can I find out what is bound to that ID? Meaning where in those 10 files is the code that is fired?

Is there anyway to see this easily using Firefox for example?

I know I could search each of the files but on a complex site with many files in many directories etc this is not an easy task, and the code might be in a file included and not a js file after all.

Have searched for a solution but found none so far.

For example:

```
<div id="exp2" onclick="expander(this); manageInvAddr();">
    <span class="info1head">Billing Address</span>
</div>
```

I want to know within which file the function `manageInvAddr();` is, but even worse, the click could be simply attached to the ID without using `onClick` so you've only an id to search for, which is problematic as there could be many ids re-used throughout a site.

Comment: Man, I've been wondering this for years...

Comment: Developer tools in Chrome, has a list of Event Listeners under the Elements tab on the right hand side. Inspect the element in question and you will see the list on the right hand side.

Comment: Thanks @IanBrindley but it doesn't show which file the code is in

Answer (score 3):

Most DOM inspectors have this built in now. However, if you want to get the events programmatically, you can use the `_data()` method of jQuery:

```
var eventsObj = $._data($('#foo')[0], "events")
```

Note that this returns an object keyed by the event type. Note also that the first parameter of the method is a native DOM element, not a jQuery object or selector.

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/gp58Lmzd/)

Answer (score 2):

Are you searching for something like this ? This is the chrome debugger tool bar.

[image: event listenner on chrome]

Comment: Yeah I've seen that but mine doesn't have things like `document` under `click` like yours shows, have just checked and my Chrome fully up to date - is there something you have to turn on?

Comment: I did not turn anything on. I'm using Chromium, not GoogleChrome if it helps.

Answer (score 2):

[Visual Event](http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event+2) has been slightly more helpful than Chrome for me because it visually displays which nodes have event bindings in addition to noting the line numbers where events are declared. Its a scriplet which allows for it to be added to all browsers (even IE).

[image]